# Angularjs - How to generate tables column dynamically onclick of ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm getting such type of response from backend.

```
 [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Roshan",
      "av": "1000",
      "compname": [
      {
        "id": "43",
        "cname": "TCS",
        "constraint_value": "",
        "details": [ {
            "id": "2",
            "emp": "Intern"
          }],

        "salaries": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "monthly_value": "1000",
            "annual_value": "12000"
          }
        ]
      }
     ]
    },

    {
     "id": "21",
     "name": "Mohan",
     "av": "1000",
     "compname": [
        {
          "id": "143",
          "cname": "Tata Constructions",
          "constraint_value": "",
          "details": [ {
              "id": "21",
              "emp": "Expeience"
            }],

          "salaries": [
            {
              "id": "10",
              "monthly_value": "1000",
              "annual_value": "12000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "11",
          "cname": "Mahindra",
          "details": [{
               "id": "2111",
              "emp": "Semi-skilled"
          }],
          "salaries": [
            {
              "id": "3",
              "monthly_value": "1200",
              "annual_value": "14400"
            }
          ]
        }
     ]
    }


    {
     "id": "121",
     "name": "Sohan",
     "av": "1000",
     "compname": [
       {
         "id": "453",
         "cname": "Roz Constructions",
         "constraint_value": "",
         "details": [ {
          "id": "211",
          "emp": "Fresher"
        }],

      "salaries": [
          {
            "id": "10",
            "monthly_value": "1000",
            "annual_value": "12000"
          }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

I am trying to create a table which will contain name. and on click of name, another column will be generated where it will show list of cname.

I tried to achieve it but I am not getting an idea of how I can display next column based on click of name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really think of accordion for handling such case. Please refer to the small code below:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Your Custom Header</th>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="ae in allEmployee">
    <tr ng-click="showCompAcc=!showCompAcc">{{ae.name}}</tr>
    <tr ng-hide="showCompAcc">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Company Names</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="cn in ae.compname">{{cn.cname}}</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This would expose an accordion on clicking every row. You cannot another column on the row click because of the json you are posting have different number of companies associated with each employee.

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: you were right, accordion can do work here. But can you help me how can accordion open the nested array on click o  parent array of ng-repeat

Comment: It would work because you would repeat the table body (as you can see in my sample code). Initially, second in body would be hidden. And as you click on the parent row it would change only "showCompAcc" variable value in the respective tbody. And hence, you would see the accordion effect on parent row click.

Comment: it will be great ig you can provide a working fiddle

Comment: I tried it, it working, but now its not hiding the currently open tab if I click on another tab. @AnandiSharma

Comment: Yes, to hide the current tab you can add a simple flag in every object in your json and initially set that to false. Create a new function in your controller, and send the id as parameter to that function on every row click. This function would iterate over the json and then set all the flag in every object in json to false except the id you send in the parameter, which would be set as true.